# How to interpret status code in Python commands.getstatusoutput()

Tags: python, command, subprocess, exit-code

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535564), I asked where to find the documentation for the C function "wait." This was an attempt to figure out return codes for the commands.getstatusoutput() module. Stackoverflow came through, but the documentation didn't help. Here's what puzzles me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands
goodcommand = 'ls /'
badcommand = 'ls /fail'
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(goodcommand)
print('Good command reported status of %s' % status)
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(badcommand)
print('Bad command reported status of %s' % status)
```

When run on OS X (Leopard) I get the following output: (Which matches the documentation.)

```
$ python waitest.py 
Good command reported status of 0
Bad command reported status of 256
```

On OS X, doing an "ls /fail ; echo $?" gets the following output:

```
$ ls /fail ; echo $?
ls: /fail: No such file or directory
1
```

When run on Linux (Ubuntu Hardy) I get the following output:

```
$ python waitest.py 
Good command reported status of 0
Bad command reported status of 512
```

On Ubuntu, doing "ls /fail" gets a 2:

```
$ ls /fail ; echo $?
ls: cannot access /fail: No such file or directory
2
```

So Python appears to be multiplying status codes by 256. Huh? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: the [answer by @Schof](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535675/52074) answers the question "when using `commands.getstatusoutput()` why are the exitcodes multiplied by 256?" directly and with example code. The other two answers more or less say "use `subprocess` instead of `commands.getstatusoutput()`" or "here's how to use subprocess".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a set of functions in `os` module (`os.WIFCONTINUED`, `os.WIFSTOPPED`, `os.WTERMSIG`, `os.WCOREDUMP`, `os.WIFEXITED`, `os.WEXITSTATUS`, `os.WIFSIGNALED`, `os.WSTOPSIG`), which correspond to macros from [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) manual. You should use them to interpret the status code.

For example, to get the exit code you should use `os.WEXITSTATUS(status)`

A better idea would be to switch to `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 4):

Wow. The insight that it was multiplying by 256 got me there. Searching for "python commands +256" got me to a [Python Module Of The Week](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/commands/index.html) article which explains what's going on.

Here's a snippet from that page:

> The function getstatusoutput() runs a
>   command via the shell and returns the
>   exit code and the text output (stdout
>   and stderr combined). The exit codes
>   are the same as for the C function
>   wait() or os.wait(). The code is a
>   16-bit number. The low byte contains
>   the signal number that killed the
>   process. When the signal is zero, the
>   high byte is the exit status of the
>   program. If a core file was produced,
>   the high bit of the low byte is set.

And some of Doug's code:

```
from commands import *

def run_command(cmd):
    print 'Running: "%s"' % cmd
    status, text = getstatusoutput(cmd)
    exit_code = status >> 8
    signal_num = status % 256
    print 'Signal: %d' % signal_num
    print 'Exit  : %d' % exit_code
    print 'Core? : %s' % bool(exit_code / 256)
    print 'Output:'
    print text
    print

run_command('ls -l *.py')
run_command('ls -l *.notthere')
run_command('echo "WAITING TO BE KILLED"; read input')
```

Comment: the return of os.system(cmd) seems to work the same way `insight that it was multiplying by 256`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at `commands.py`:

```
def getstatusoutput(cmd):
    """Return (status, output) of executing cmd in a shell."""
    import os
    pipe = os.popen('{ ' + cmd + '; } 2>&1', 'r')
    text = pipe.read()
    sts = pipe.close()
    if sts is None: sts = 0
    if text[-1:] == '\n': text = text[:-1]
    return sts, text
```

We see `sts` holds the value of `os.popen(...).close()`.  Looking at [*that* documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen), `os.popen(...).close()` returns the value of [`os.wait`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.wait):

> `os.wait()`
>
> Wait for completion of a child process, and return a tuple containing its pid and exit status indication: a 16-bit number, whose low byte is the signal number that killed the process, and **whose high byte is the exit status** (if the signal number is zero); the high bit of the low byte is set if a core file was produced. Availability: Unix.

Emphasis was mine.  I agree that this "encoding" isn't terribly intuitive, but at least it was fairly obvious at a glance that it was being multiplied/bit-shifted.

Comment: Thank you for the emphasis, I was pretty confused by what I was seeing until I read this..

Answer (score 0):

I think the code detection is incorrect.

"If a core file was produced, the high bit of the low byte is set." means 128.

so I think the core line should be

```
print 'Core? : %s' % bool(status & 128)
```